# Any high level library or framework to hook all events in one's app in C#?

Tags: c#, frameworks

I know there's hook in Win32 but I don't need to hook the whole system and it's low level.

What I want is something easy like Wordpress framework but for Winform which allows me to hook all events in my own application for example detecting all textbox leave or all forms closing.

Does this exist ? Is it possible technically or only Microsoft can do so in .NET Version X.X ?

Comment: Why on earth do people vote down for no reason ? If they don't know the answer or the question is too advanced for them ?

Comment: upvoted to equalize for you.  Maybe you'll share the love and upvote my answer, if you find it helpful. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [ManagedSpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx).  It's an application very similar to Spy++, but for managed applications.  It appeared in an MSDN Magazine issue several years ago.

When you run ManagedSpy, you can attach it to a running .Net process.  It will reflect on the assemblies and find all kinds of events (there's some filtering ability to only see certain events), then it attaches to them and outputs the sequence of them firing.

There is also [source code for ManagedSpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164593.aspx), so you can see how they did things and use those ideas to build what you need.

Comment: I knew this existed but couldn't remember what it was called! :D

Comment: I only remember because the month that issue arrived in my mail box I had already spent a *lot* of time figuring out event order on some WinForms stuff.  ManagedSpy saved my butt that month.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this as I am aware. There are external tools that can help (such as Spy++) but I believe they operate at the Windows message level rather than the .NET event level.

If you really need to do this level of monitoring in your application, you'll need to sign up event handlers on each object you wish to monitor. You could consider writing code that walks the control tree for each `Form` and signs up their events, so you could run it at startup after the forms are created.